# Problems exiting C# program that uses R.Net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, r.net

I have a small program in C# that loads the R.Net library to outsource some calculations that I can't do in c#, namely the Twitter anomaly detection library. Unfortunately, when the code finishes the console window it runs in hangs. If I run it in debug, code execution seems to be error free, so I suspect it's something to do with cleanup of the REngine as I (eventually) get an error as per this image.

[image: Error message thrown by VS Community 2015, Update 3]

After which I'll get another pop up from VS stating "Debugging is stopped but is not yet complete, either force it to stop by pressing this button or continue to wait".

Code is approximately as follows:

```
class SHESD_Test
{
    private static REngine engine;

    internal SHESD_Test(IEnumerable<Double> d)
    {
        try
        {
            if(engine==null)
            {
                engine = REngine.GetInstance();
                engine.Initialize();
                engine.Evaluate("library(AnomalyDetection)"); //Loads Twitter library
            }
            var dInR = engine.CreateNumericVector(d.toArray());
            engine.SetSymbol("data", dInR);
            var outVar = engine.Evaluate("outVar <- AnomalyDetectionVec(data, max_anoms=0.02, direction='both', plot=FALSE, period=96)");
            /* Some other stuff that grabs data out of outVar in R and stores in member variables */

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { /* Log error */ }
    }
    //Called from elsewhere once everything is complete, but behaviour is the same if I don't call it
    internal static void cleanup()         
    {
        engine.ForceGarbageCollection();
        engine.Dispose();
        engine == null;
    }
}
```

Googling the error code, it looks like a timeout has expired, but for the life of me I can't figure out why.

The code itself executes fine, it's only in the exit from main(), and not the bit where the REngine falls out of scope, so perhaps in garbage collection things are going awry?

Comment: Just throwing this out there; `REngine` clearly implements `IDisposable`.  The whole issue may go away if instead of using a `static` class variable you put it in a `using` block.

Comment: I did it this way as I create this class multiple times. Perhaps I should create the REngine in the calling class with a "using" and sent it in via the constructor - will give it a whirl

Comment: If you put your `using` inside `SHESD_Test`, it'll create the instance, run all functions on it, and then dispose of it every time `SHESD_Test` is called. Unless it's a memory hog, that's probably the way to go, and you'll not have to test for `if(engine==null)`'

Comment: It still exhibits the same behaviour with a "using" call :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging further, the root cause is in the library function generating a plot window in it's return value, even when told not to. Their code is:

```
# Lastly, return anoms and optionally the plot if requested by the user
if(plot){
    return (list(anoms = anoms, plot = xgraph))
} else {
    return (list(anoms = anoms, ***plot = plot.new()***)) # <-Looky here!
}
```

Adding to my code the following line when I'm done with the engine:

```
engine.Evaluate("graphics.off()");
```

closes the strange empty window, which doesn't seem to be able to be closed by either the ForceGarbageCollection or Dispose methods - probably leaving things hanging about waiting for something that will never happen, and thus triggering this timeout exception window.